# ODATA Service creation with Java?

Tags: java, odata

Is there any sort of ODATA support for Java? I know there are plenty of rest based libraries out there like Jersey, etc. though I would like to utilize ODATA without .NET. and if so, any good guides?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [odata4j](http://odata4j.org)?

Let us know if you have suggestions on the documentation.

Thanks,
- john